# Gremlin: Emit vetex levels as a list from a breath first seach

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I have a graph where edges with certain labels form a tree with defined start and leaf vertices.

[image: Tree levels diagram]

I want to perform a breadth first search and emit the vertices of each level of the tree as a separate list for further processing.

So far, I can get the vertices in the correct order using the query below:

```
g.V()
.hasLabel("root")
.repeat(out("tree_edge").barrier().dedup())
.emit()
.until(outE("tree_edge").count().is(0))
```

However this results in a single list:

```
==>v[64]
==>v[72]
==>v[80]
==>v[88]
==>v[208]
==>v[176]
==>v[216]
==>v[184]
==>v[192]
==>v[136]
==>v[152]
==>v[104]
==>v[120]
==>v[128]
==>v[144]
==>v[96]
```

Where what I want is something more like:

```
==>[v[64], v[72], v[80], v[88]]
==>[v[208], v[176], v[216], v[184], v[192]]
==>[v[136], v[152], v[104], v[120], v[128], v[144], v[96]]
```

I an not sure what I need to add to the repeat step for it to emit a list instead of the individual vertices. I played around with `cap`, `project` and `fold` to no avail.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group the vertices by their depth in the tree, then sort the final group-map and return all values:

```
g.V().hasLabel("root").
  group("m").
    by(constant(-1)).
  repeat(out("tree_edge").dedup().group("m").by(loops())).
    until(__.not(outE("tree_edge"))).
  cap("m").
  order(local).
    by(keys).
  select(values).unfold()
```